# Compare two string representations of IP address in MS SQL 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, ip

I have the following table on my MS SQL 2012 database server:

```
CREATE TABLE ip_lookup (
ip_start varchar(16) NOT NULL, // like 5.200.100.0
ip_end varchar(16) NOT NULL,   // like 5.202.255.255
country char(2) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ip_start));
```

I cannot change the structure of this table because it is updated quite often - once per 2-3 days.

I need to get country for specific IP given the table above. Therefore I need some comparer to find the correct row. I see the following approaches:

- Store ip_start and ip_end as unsigned int32 and then it's quite easy to compare them. (not an option for me because I can not change table schema)
- Split each IP into four octets (which should also be integers because strings are compared alphabetically and `2.2.10.2` is less then `2.2.2.2`)

Is there another way to compare two string IPs using MS SQL?

Comment: [Indexed Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx) *might* be useful, if they are allowed (and can be used to implement any of the currently proposed approaches). Anyway, also consider IPv6 compatibility O_o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you could store the strings in a "zero-padded" format, then you can accomplish what you want just with strings.  So, `5.200.100.0` would be `005.200.100.000`.  Then direct string comparisons would work, and queries could take advantage of indexes.

When working with IPs, I almost always have the internal format (32-bit or 128-bit) along with the string representation.  The internal format is really needed to prevent comparison errors.

If your performance is not an issue, you can convert from the string form to a binary form or character form.  For that purpose, `parsename()` can be quite useful (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)).  Normally when working with IPs, performance *is* an issue, so you should look for a way to store the data more effectively.